# jquery selectors to get image path

Tags: jquery, image, path, selector

when user clicks on class click_1, I want to get the path of the image shown. Note that click_1 occurs in two contexts.

```
<a href="#" class='click_1' ><img src="assets/img/shoe05.png" /></a>
<h4><a href="#" class='click_1' >title link 2</a></h4></li>


    $('.click_1').click(function() {            
        var fullPath = $(this).children("img:first").attr('src');
        if (typeof fullPath === "undefined"){
                        // this one does not work...
            var fullPath = $(this).prev("img").children("img:first").attr('src');
            console.log(fullPath);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap both in a single `<a />` tag? That's now valid, as of HTML5.

```
<a href="#" class='click_1'>
    <img src="assets/img/shoe05.png" />
    <h4>title link 2</h4>
</a>
```

```js
$('.click_1').click(function() {            
    var src = $(this).children('img').first().attr('src');
    console.log(src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the correct element to a var, check if it exists, then pull out the 'src'.  Something like this:

```
$('.click_1').click(function() {            
    var imgElement = $(this).find("img").first();
    if (imgElement.length){
        var fullPath = imgElement.attr('src');
        console.log(fullPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that class `click_1` is unique for this section of related code, you could use this:

```
$('.click_1').click(function() {            

    var element = $(this).find('img').first() || $('.click_1 img').first();
    var fullPath = element.attr('src');

    console.log(fullPath);
});
```

However, something tells me it would be better to set up a function that takes your class name as argument, so you can execute it for multiple click_X elements on your page. (need more info)

Comment: Never use `[0]`, only to create a jQuery object again. Use `eq(0)` or `first()` instead.